# Listen for clipboard changes in the background of a uwp application?

Tags: c#, service, clipboard, win-universal-app

I have been searching for a way to listen for clipboard changes in a universal windows platform application. I want to be able to have a service that is running in the background, regardless of the application state, that listens for clipboard changes. I have been searching, but it seems like the uwp does not have a service class like android does.

Thanks in advance,

Seth

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple and you can to it like this :

```
Clipboard.ContentChanged += (s, e) => 
{
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        string text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
        // To output the text from this example, you need a TextBlock control
        TextOutput.Text = "Clipboard now contains: " + text;
    }
}
```

For more you can read [MSDN - Copy and paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243291.aspx)

Comment: I know how to read the clipboard, but I want to be able to monitor it at all times, even with the application closed.

Comment: @SethLessard So I suggest you this sample project, hope this one help you  [BackgroundTask](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask)

Answer (score 0):

> listen for clipboard changes in a universal windows platform application.

Listening for clipboard changes in UWP app is not supported.

You'll need to use a background task to monitor system even when the foreground process is suspended. Below is a list of all supported system triggers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx.

Clipboard event is not supported in BackgroundTask triggers.